# Как вывести в процентном соотношении значения списка?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Есть следующий код:

```
queries = [
'смотреть сериалы онлайн',
'новости спорта',
'афиша кино',
'курс доллара',
'сериалы этим летом',
'курс по питону',
'сериалы про спорт']
for value in queries:
    percent = round(len(queries)/len(value)*100, 1)
    word = round(len(value) / len(queries))
    print('Поисковых запросов, содержащих', word, 'слов(а):', percent ,'%')
```

Необходимо, чтобы результат был :

```
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 2 слов(а): 42.86%
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 3 слов(а): 57.14%.
```

А выходит:

```
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 3 слов(а): 30.4 %
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 2 слов(а): 50.0 %
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 1 слов(а): 70.0 %
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 2 слов(а): 58.3 %
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 3 слов(а): 38.9 %
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 2 слов(а): 50.0 %
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 2 слов(а): 41.2 %.
```

То есть код считает каждую фразу по отношению к общей длине списка.

Как исправить код, чтобы вышло то, что ожидается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words = [len(qry.split()) for qry in queries]

for w in sorted(set(words)):
    print(f"Поисковых запросов, содержащих {w} слов(а): {words.count(w)/len(queries):.2%}")
```

вывод:

```
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 2 слов(а): 42.86%
Поисковых запросов, содержащих 3 слов(а): 57.14%
```

Comment: спасибо) А можете объяснить, что такое qry?

Comment: @Alina, `qry` - переменная цикла (`list comprehension`). Запустите: `[qry for qry in queries]`, потом `[qry.split() for qry in queries]` и потом `[len(qry.split()) for qry in queries]`, чтобы понять как работает каждый шаг...

Comment: поняла, спасибо)